# Convert list to vector in python

Tags: python, list, numpy, matrix, vector

I'd like to convert a long list into a matrix or vector in order to convert it to degrees. I don't want to use a "for" loop because the list is too long and I want my program to be as fast as possible. How could I do this?

EDIT:

This is what I've tried so far,

```
latR=np.asarray(lat)
latR=np.degrees(latR)
```

but this is what I get:

```
ufunc 'degrees' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you copy/pasted your error into Google, what did you find?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, first a suggestion add the "numpy" tag to make your question more specific, then can you tell us on which line the error shows? Because i think is on the second line (np.concatenate...) but not sure.

Comment: The error suggests `lat` contains data that is not numeric, or that numpy doesn't know how to handle.  Can you include a short example of the data? (following guidelines in https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you look at `latR` after the `asarray` function?  What's its `dtype`? `shape`?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do `np.degrees(lat)` on your initial list.

A "vector" is simply a 1D array (what you get by the first line). The `concatenate` adds new elements to your array, so, not needed here. So, you could just omit the second line, but there's no need to even to that. Use `degrees` onto the list directly.

Comment: I tried just np.degrees(lat), but received this error message: ufunc 'degrees' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: You have some non-number values in your list

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my list was made up of strings instead of floats as I had assumed... This was all that was needed to convert, then plot what was needed:

```
latD = np.degrees(latitude)              
lonD = np.degrees(longitude)             

xs, ys = m(lonD, latD)
m.plot(xs, ys,linewidth = 3,color = 'r')
```